# NodeJS async class with singleton design pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, singleton

**Problem:**
Implement the singleton design pattern with async calls in the class. I can't get the values when i import the module into a second file.

**Case:**
Eventually i want to implement this logic for a bearer token update when it expires. I have multiple functions that relies on the token. So when i get a 403 i will update the token and all the other function have acces to this updated token as well.

**Script 1:**

```
//File1.js
import axios from "axios";

async function getJson(n) {
  const req = await axios.get(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${n}`
  );
  return req.data.title;
}

class Todo {
  constructor() {
    if (Todo.instance == null) {
      this.title;
      Todo.instance = this;
    }
    return Todo.instance;
  }

  async init() {
    this.title = await getJson(1);
  }

  async updateTodo(n) {
    this.title = await getJson(n);
  }

  getTodo() {
    return this.title;
  }
}

const todo = await new Todo().init();

export default todo;
```

**Script 2:**

```
const todo = await import('./File1.js');

console.log(todo); //[Module: null prototype] { default: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)] }
todo.updateTodo(3) //TypeError: todo.updateTodo is not a function
```

**Script 2.1:**

```
import todo from './File1.js';
await todo.init();

console.log(todo.getTodo())
await todo.updateTodo(2)
console.log(todo.getTodo())
```

Comment: For dynamic imports, the module you're looking for would be `todo.default`, so `todo.default.updateTodo(3)`.

Comment: @code thank you for your reply. Still get `todo.default.updateTodo(3) //TypeError: todo.updateTodo is not a function`

Comment: Did you reload, save, or restart your server? Apparently your changes weren't applied.

Comment: @code i just updated file2 and run `node File2.js` in the console on my mac.

Comment: Ah, you're running on Node, I forgot. Can you confirm that you saved the file?

Comment: @code yes i'm sure. No orange bolls on top of the file ;) [screenshot](https://ibb.co/sgCMLFN)

Comment: Oh, okay. This looks like another problem I spot. `await new Todo()`. Why are you awaiting a new Todo? You know the only thing that will happen is promisify your todo. By the way, no, you can't return values in a constructor. Try creating another function called something like `init()` and add the features in there instead.

Comment: @code the reasons is that i want to export a single instance of the class and not the class itself, so before exporting i want the initial title to be filled from the api.

Comment: I was talking about the `await`, not about the instance creation. Again, constructors can't return values. Also, in that case it would be `await new Todo()();`.

Comment: @code it worked. Thank you for your help. Above the 2.1 script worked with the updated `File1.js`

Comment: Good for you! Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic imports are different from regular imports. When you do:

```js
import module from "./module.js";
```

`module` will be equal to the default export, something like:

```js
// module.js
export default function module() {
  // do something
}
```

In dynamic imports (`import()`), however, you have to manually access the default export:

```js
const importModule = await import("./module.js");
const module = importModule.default;
module(); // default export module
```

So in your code you would be doing:

```js
todo.default.updateTodo(3);
```